# How to make compiled Fortran code work on a different computer?

Tags: ssh, fortran, gfortran

I compiled a piece of Fortran code and the execution works perfectly on my computer. However, I copied the executable in a remote server and tried to execute it through SSH. The following error came up:

```
-bash: ./ex2.exe: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I looked up uname -m in Terminal with the same results for both my own machine and the remote one:

```
x86_64
```

My own code works perfectly and I just want to be able to execute it in a remote server. To compile it I used:

```
gfortran -O3 -o isingmodel.exe isingmodel.f
```

I must mention that the remote server doesn't have gfortran so I can't upload the .f file and compile it in the server.

Comment: This has nothing to do with or ssh and little to do with Fortran specifically. You must tell us the exact configuration of both your PC and your server. As exactly as possible. Hardware and software. The operating system, the compiler, 32bit or 64bit, everything matters. I hope that your PC is at least running Linux. Most likely, you have to install gfortran on your server anyway.

Comment: I have a MacBook Air running OSX with 64-bit Core i5. The remote server is running  Ubuntu version #168-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 16 21:00:45 UTC 2019 and is also 64-bit. I just realised the remote server has gcc installed, so it should include gfortran right?

Comment: You **cannot** use a MacOS binary in Linux. You have to install a Fortran compiler at the Linux computer. Any compiler that is available.

Comment: Your situation is "normal". If you ssh to another computer, that other computer may be managed by an IT staff, ask them for support.

Comment: A possible way to deal with this: get an emulator ([VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) should do). Install the same version of Linux in the emulator, with gfortran. Compile your program as a *static* executable (or alternately find all dependencies and copy them along with your program). Note that having gcc does not necessarily mean gfortran is available (it's another package). The *best* way is to ask IT to install gfortran though (but I know from experience that sometimes IT is reluctant).